# UIActionSheet on iPad comes up from the bottom when the parent view is a UIPopover

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

On iPad, I have a view that is a popover. There is a button inside the view that shows a UIActionSheet. When I call showFromBarButtonItem:animated, instead of showing up as a popover as I would expect, I instead get an action sheet that comes up from the bottom of the view. Does anyone know a way to force it to be a popover on top of the existing popover? Everything works fine if my view that shows the UIActionSheet is not a popover.

Comment: Did you tried this?         [popoverActionsheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];

Comment: @AmitVyawahare yes I try that, but instead of showing it as a popover, it comes up from the bottom of the view (like the iPhone). On iPad it should be a popover always...

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is probably because you are calling the UIActionSheet object from within your popover controller, which probably has bounds comparable to that of the iPhone screen size. When you call from within this controller the method `showFromBarButtonItem:animated:` it gets the bounds of this reduced size popover controller and launches the action sheet object just like on an iPhone from the bottom.

What you would probably need to do is nest popover controllers to achieve your desired effect.